# Starting service mongodb fail on Permission denied: "/sys/devices/system/node/node1"

Tags: mongodb

i got a problem with mongo on a ubuntu server precise 12.04, after apt-get install mongodb-10gen, when i try "mongo", got this error :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem3::filesystem_error'
what():  boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/sys/devices/system/node/node1"
Aborted
```

I tried to look "/sys/devices/system/node/node1" permissions but it seems not to exist.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 8):

Did you install on a OVH server?

I had the same issue today, and it turned out to be a kernel issue (I chose a "approved by OVH kernel"). Installing a stock Ubuntu kernel solved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue on an OVH server, but I didn't want to reinstall with another kernel...

My workaround was to create a group "sysfs" and add "mongodb" user to this group.

Then I did several "chgrp sysfs ..." and "chmod g+rx ..." so that sysfs group can have read access to the directories needed by mongodb:

- /sys/devices/system/node
- /sys/dev/block/
- /sys/devices/virtual/block/md1/queue

Indeed /sys/devices/system/node/node1 doesn't exist, but read access on /sys/devices/system/node was enough.

Note the "mongo" client has the same restriction, so all the users who need it must be added to "sysfs" group as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with an OVH debian and solved the problem in a surprisingly simple way: chmod 755 on /sys/devices/system/node/node1 and parent directories.

Comment: chmod 755 /sys/devices/system/node/node1 gave an error but was able to run chmod 755 /sys/devices/system/node/ and for parent directories to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corresponding bug report in mongodb:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10623

It notes that this has been fixed in 2.5.3

Comment: Odd, I still seem to be experiencing this error in 2.5.4.

Comment: as noted in the last comment, they also have https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12464, which is fixed in 2.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with OVH/kimsufi.

I installed default kernel and everything works at least at the time of writing, albeit system became noticeably slower and less responsive.

You will need

1. Install new kernell
2. Make in bootable. I was banging my head against the wall for couple of hours before I've realized I haven't made new kernel bootable.

First, make a backup copy of `/etc/default/grub` and then follow on the guides, for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/156700/how-to-set-default-boot-kernel-in-ubuntu-grub or  https://askubuntu.com/questions/309874/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-9-in-ubuntu or https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order